# TSQL command "Create Assembly" fails verification on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, clr, sql-server-2014, sqlclr

I am experimenting with adding custom support for the [R language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)) into SQL Server 2014.

I want to install MEF, to allow this to occur.

I run this SQL ...

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [System.ComponentModel.Composition]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
```

... but I get this error:

```
Warning: The Microsoft .NET Framework assembly 'system.componentmodel.composition, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089.' you are registering is not fully tested in the SQL Server hosted environment and is not supported. In the future, if you upgrade or service this assembly or the .NET Framework, your CLR integration routine may stop working. Please refer SQL Server Books Online for more details.
Msg 6218, Level 16, State 2, Line 56
CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'System.ComponentModel.Composition' failed because assembly 'System.ComponentModel.Composition' failed verification. Check if the referenced assemblies are up-to-date and trusted (for external_access or unsafe) to execute in the database. CLR Verifier error messages if any will follow this message
[ : Microsoft.Internal.Assumes::NotNull[T]][mdToken=0x6000001][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : Microsoft.Internal.Assumes::NotNull[T1,T2]][mdToken=0x6000002][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : Microsoft.Internal.Assumes::NotNull[T1,T2,T3]][mdToken=0x6000003][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : Microsoft.Internal.Assumes::Null[T]][mdToken=0x6000005][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : Microsoft.Internal.Assumes::NotReachable[T]][mdToken=0x600000a][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : Microsoft.Internal.Assumes::NotNullOrEmpty][mdToken=0x6000004][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : Microsoft.Internal.Assumes::IsFalse][mdToken=0x6000006][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : Microsoft.Internal.Assumes::IsTrue][mdToken=0x6000007][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : Microsoft.Internal.Assumes::IsTrue][mdToken=0x6000008][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : Microsoft.Internal.Assumes::Fail][mdToken=0x6000009][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : Microsoft.Internal.AttributeServices::GetAttributes[T]][mdToken=0x600000b][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : Microsoft.Internal.AttributeServices::GetAttributes[T]][mdToken=0x600000c][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : Microsoft.Internal.AttributeServices::GetFirstAttribute[T]][mdToken=0x600000d][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : Microsoft.Internal.AttributeServices::GetFirstAttribute[T]][mdToken=0x600000e][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : Microsoft.Internal.AttributeServices::IsAttributeDefined[T]][mdToken=0x600000f][offset 0x00000000] Code size is zero.
[ : Microsoft.Internal.AttributeServices::IsAttributeDefined[T]][mdToken=0x6000010][offset 0...
```

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that I was [using the "reference" .dll, not the actual "framework" .dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835036/cant-add-system-io-compression-to-trusted-assemblies-in-sql-server). This worked nicely:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [System.ComponentModel.Composition]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
from 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
```

To avoid having to guess which folder to import from, run this query:

```
select * from sys.dm_clr_properties
```

[image]

Comment: If anyone finds the linked answer regarding [reference vs actual DLL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835036/cant-add-system-io-compression-to-trusted-assemblies-in-sql-server) useful, please don't forget to upvote that answer ;-).

Comment: Done! And if you can figure out a way of loading mixed mode assemblies into SQLCLR, I'll figure out a way to give you 50 reputation :)

Comment: Thanks. And unfortunately it is not possible to load mixed-mode Assemblies. That is very much a restriction, which disallows loading certain Framework libraries. Is that the issue?

Comment: I was hoping I could use a super-fast C++ implementation in the database, but it appears as if this is not possible if its wrapped in C#. I'll have to figure out another way.

Comment: You can call unmanaged code via COM wrappers. Would that help? I have seen folks do that to get base Windows calls.